# XY Resolution of Form 3 Printer versus Laser Spot Size

Tags: sla, resolution

According to the Formlabs site, the XY resolution (with the appropriate resin) is 25 microns.  However the laser spot diameter is listed as 85 microns.  Assuming the 85 microns is FWHM (full width half max), unless the sensitivity of the resin is quite non-linear, I don't see how it is possible to achieve a 25 micron resolution.  Does anyone have any hard data on the measured resolution of the Form 3 printer?

Comment: Both values must be referring to different properties, one will be the positioning of the laser, the other the laser deposit width.

Comment: Oscar, unfortunately, you are probably correct.  I know of others who have used the precision of their scanning as the XY resolution.

Comment: Printer (as in: printer on paper :) manufacturers have always been guilty of making the same misprepresentation: the dot size they deposit is usually larger (sometimes _much_ larger) than its positioning accuracy.